# Existence of Riemann integrable sequence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-integration

Can someone help me do this problem?

Let $f$ be s Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ not necessarily continuous.Prove that there exists a sequence $\{g_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b |g_n(x)-f(x)|\ dx=0$$

Comment: The definition of Riemann integrability gives you a sequence of piecewise constant functions with this property. Can you work out how to "slightly" modify a piecewise constant function to make it continuous?

Comment: @Ian : I am not getting it.. Yes I understand your technique but my doubt is :the definition requires a particular value over each interval of the partition, how to make it continuous over the interval?

Comment: What I'm saying is, the definition gives you a sequence of piecewise constant functions $p_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b |p_n(x) - f(x)| dx = 0$. Now suppose you had a sequence of continuous functions $g_n$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b |p_n(x)-g_n(x)| dx = 0$. Then by the triangle inequality you would have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b |g_n(x)-f(x)| dx = 0$. So how can you imagine making such a sequence $g_n$? Drawing a picture may help.

Comment: If $f=c_i$ on $[a_i,b_i)$, and every point is in one of these intervals, then $\int_a^b f(t) dt = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i(b_i-a_i)$.

Comment: @Ian : Can you please help me define $\int _x^y f(t)dt$ where $f(t)$ is a step function. $\sum$ is well well defined I know over $p_n= U(P,f,\alpha)= \sum ^n_{i=1} M_i \Delta \alpha _i$ *(I assume P to be the partition of* $[a,b] $ such that U is infimum)

Comment: My $p_n$ is not a partition, it's a function.